# Complexity of recurrence equation 6

Tags: recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

$B(n)=B(⌈ n/\log_2 n⌉)+\theta(n)$

B(2)=1

Here is my attempt:

\begin{align*}
B(n)
&= 3B(\lceil n/\log_2 n\rceil) + \Theta(n)\\
&= 3\big(3B(\lceil n/(\log_2 n)^2\rceil) + \Theta(n)\big) + \Theta(n)\\
&= 3\big(3\big(3B(\lceil n/(\log_2 n)^3\rceil)\big)\big) + 3^2\Theta(n) + 3\Theta(n) + \Theta(n)\\
&\ \ \vdots\\
&= 3^{k-1}B(\lceil n/(\log_2n)^{k-1}\rceil) + (1 + 3 + \dots + 3^{k-1})\Theta(n)\\
&= 3^{k-1} B(\lceil n/(\log_2 n)^{k-1}\rceil) + \frac{3^k-1}{3-1}\Theta(n)\,.
\end{align*}

I want to eliminate B(n) then I can just consider a variable times $\theta(n)$

Is there a substitution that I can use to make the term inside the function become 2?

Or any other smart method I can use to solve this problem?

Comment: FYI - posting pictures of handwritten stuff like this instead of writing it out in mathjax is practically screaming "I want you to put a lot of effort to help me, but I can't be bothered to put any effort into making it easier for you to do so".

Comment: Also, you haven't even explained what you are trying to do.

Comment: How do you justify the fact that you only "recurse" on the $\log_2 n$, in the argument of $B$? Technically, it should be $B(\lceil \frac{n}{\log n}\rceil )$, then $B(\lceil \frac{m}{\log m}\rceil )$ for $m=\lceil \frac{n}{\log n}\rceil$, etc. (the expressions are very close, but not equal.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this. Now my issue is I have no idea about how to spot the substitution in this expression @Clement C.

Comment: If I may, where is this question from?